# MONOTOUCH get row item selected

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have a navigation controller to show a list o item on table, then I need to touch an item a show the details of this item.

Here it's my code of how a fill the table:

```
public void SearchHotel (){

    Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
    var distribution = new HotelDistribution[]{new HotelDistribution(){ Adults = 1, Children = 0, ChildrenAges = new int[0]} };
    var items = hotel.SearchHotels(Convert.ToDateTime("2013-08-08"),Convert.ToDateTime("2013-09-09 "),"(MIA)", distribution,"","","",0);


    data = new List<DtoHotelinformation>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        DtoHotelinformation DtoHotelinformation = new DtoHotelinformation();
        DtoHotelinformation.code  = item.Code.ToString();
        DtoHotelinformation.price  = item.Price.ToString();
        DtoHotelinformation.title =  item.Name.ToString().ToTitleCase();
        DtoHotelinformation.subtitle = item.Address.ToString();
        DtoHotelinformation.rating  = item.Rating.ToString();
        DtoHotelinformation.imageUlr = item.ImageUrl;

        data.Add(DtoHotelinformation);
    }

    hud.Hide(true);
    hud.RemoveFromSuperview();
    HotelSearchTable.Source = new HotelTableSource(data.ToArray());
    HotelSearchTable.ReloadData();

}
```

Because I'm using storyboard to show the details view controller I have this code on my table source:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    if (RowTouched != null) {
        RowTouched (this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
}
```

Back in to my viewcontroller I call the RowTouched to show the details controller like this:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated) {
    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
    SearchHotel ();

    var source = new HotelTableSource(data.ToArray());
    var detail = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("HotelDetailScreen") as  iPhoneHotelDetailViewController;
    source.RowTouched += (sender, e) => {
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(detail, true);

    };
    HotelSearchTable.Source = source;

}
```

But I need to pass the information of the item touched on the table to show the details. I don't really don't know what do I have to do?

NOTE: I can't use PrepareForSegue because I don't have a segue between controllers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can get a hold of your UINavigationController 
from within your Row Selected event, inside of your Table Data Source.

From there you can push your new ViewController.

[indexPath.Row] in "Row_Selected" should tell you which element in your array or list, that the user has selected.

```
UINavigationController navcontroller =(UINavigationController)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing data to an event handler is exatly what the EventArgs parameter is for.

Create a class that inherits from EventArgs and has properties for the data you need:

```
public class HotelSelectedEventARgs : EventArgs
{
  public DTOHotelInformation HotelInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you call your handler in RowSelected, instead of passing an empty EventArgs, create an instance of your custom class and assign the selected data to the HotelInfo property.